# Regular expression matching Yit::t methods containing specific word

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I'm new to regular expressions. I want to know if there is any way to find all occurrences of `something` in an example like below:

```
Yii::t('something', 'Create')
```

Note that, `something` might contain dashes and spaces, all other parts are static.

It should match following examples:

```
Yii::t('bla bla', 'Create')
Yii::t('cmdshdfjs', 'Create')
...
```

Only `something` changes, in other words.

Comment: @anubhava for example?

Comment: Does the string always start with `Yii::t('` and end with `', 'Create')`?

Comment: Never mind the dashes and spaces. Can `something` contain apostrophes?

Comment: @PatrickMurphy yes. Changes only `something`

Comment: parsing php with a regular expression is a bad idea - do you really have to do this

Comment: @Dagon i'm finding and replacing all occurences in IDE

Comment: most IDE's have tools to do this

Comment: @Jack no sir. I didn't tagged php

Comment: @Dagon IDE requires regex:)

Comment: @Ja͢ck provided. updated question

Comment: `(?<=\bYii::t\()(['"]).*?\1(?=,\s*(['"])Create\2\);)` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex that is using look-behind to make sure we match `Yii::t('` before our match and the look-ahead that checks for `', 'Create')` after:

```
(?<=\bYii::t\(')(?:[^'\\]|\\.)+(?=',\s*'Create'\))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU9kV2/3)

It also accounts for escaped `'`s.